# Input `Reduce[Mod[a + x, l] == 0, x]' and output `x == -a + kl`?

Tags: equation-solving, functions

```
Reduce[a + x == k l && k > 0, x]
(* k > 0 && x == -a + k l *)
```

I think `a + x == k l` and `Mod[a + x, l] == 0` are equivalent, but when I replace `a + x == k l` by Mod, Mathematica can't produce the previous result.

```
Reduce[Mod[a + x, l] == 0, x, Integers]
(*
Reduce::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce.
Reduce[Mod[a + x, l] == 0, x, Integers]
*)
```

Do I miss certain conditions to let the command work?

Comment: `k l == k*l != kl`

Comment: Even I run `Reduce[a + x == k l && k > 0, x]` (with a space between k and l), Mathematica can also do the reduce.

Comment: `Reduce[Sin[Pi (a + x)/l] == 0, x, Integers]` seems to work. Perhaps *M is not programmed to handle `Mod` with an arbitrary modulus.